# Random numbers used in TLS

Tags: tls, random

I found in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) about TLS v1.2 that *master_secret* is computed this way:

```
master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret, "master secret",
                          ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random)
```

while, subsequently, the needed key blocks composing the key material are generated through

```
  key_block = PRF(SecurityParameters.master_secret,
                  "key expansion",
                  SecurityParameters.server_random +
                  SecurityParameters.client_random);
```

And here it is my question: is there any difference between *SecurityParameters.server_random* and *ServerHello.random* or between the corresponding client's random numbers? And if yes, what is this difference?

---

My opinion: I think *SecurityParameters.master_secret* is the one computed with the first PRF shown above: so - supposing this "asymmetry" of notation - maybe, also the random numbers in the second PRF are the same used in the first? But, if so, why this different notation?

Answer (score 1):

The master-to-working key derivation is defined as part of the Record Protocol in section 6, and therefore uses only the 'parameters' passed through a theoretical API from the Handshake Protocol in section 7.3 and 7.4 (and 8) which can directly process the handshake messages including both Hello's and the KeyExchange(s) and/or Certificate(s) contents. I suspect this thinking may have come at least in part from IPSec where the data-level 'bearer' processing is largely isolated from the setup/management processing. In practice no SSL/TLS implementation I have looked at enforces this separation; there are normally code blocks (methods etc) for the two protocol levels that are separately usable (and need to be) but share session/connection/crypto state.

Also, it's not clear at all from the notation, but the premaster-to-master happens only when a full handshake (key exchange) is done, while the master-to-working is repeated if and each time a session is resumed using an abbreviated handshake, using the new nonces from the new abbreviated handshake not the ones from the original full handshake; see F.1.4.

Comment: The point about the abbreviated handshake is very interesting, thank you. Referring to my question, can I therefore assume that random numbers used in the computation of the master secret and of the key block both refer to the ones exchanged in the hello messages, even if they are referenced in different ways?